# I want to login via ajax call using html begin form in MVC with return url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to log in via ajax call using HTML begin to form in MVC with return url.
How can I solve this one?
My page is refreshing I don't want to reload again when redirecting to another page.
I am unable to stop refreshing page after ajax call. I have tried by putting e.preventDefault(), and return false; as well but again my page is refreshing.
here is my ajax call

```
<script>
   $('.btnUrl').click(function (e) {

               debugger
               e.preventDefault();
               //collect the user data
               var data = {};
               data.UserName = $("#username").val();
               data.Password = $("#password").val();
               var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
               //var url = $('.btnUrl').data('url');
               $.ajax({
                   url: "/Account/Login",
                   method: "POST",
                   data: {
                       model: data,
                       __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                       returnUrl: "Home/Index"   // you can modify the returnUrl value here
                   },
                   success: function (data) {
                       debugger
                       if (data.Success) {

                           window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index" ,"Home")";
                       }
                       else {

                           window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Login" ,"Account")";
                       }
                   }
                   });
           });

       </script>
```

my action  method

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true

            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                   // return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                return Json(new { Success = true, Url = "/Home/Index" });

                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new {/* ReturnUrl = returnUrl,*/ RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");

                    return Json(new { Success = false, Url = "/Account/Login" });
                    //return View(model);
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

        }
```

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. To use ajax when you want to redirect is pointless. Just make a normal submit and redirect in the POST method

Answer (score 0):

You are using `window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index" ,"Home")";` in your `ajax` success, which reloads the entire page. If you don't want to reload the page then in `ajax` success return partial view from your controller. Like this

```
success: function (partialViewData) {
           $('body').html(partialViewData); // change where ever you want to place the view
          }
```

Comment: Hi, I want to redirect my page from login to index of Home how can I do in ajax?

Comment: make a partial view(for your index page) and after user validation from the controller return that partial view to ajax success and replace body html with the returned html

Answer (score 0):

Your code handling the 'click' event of an button. What you want is to handle the 'submit' event of the form and using `e.preventDefault();` to cancel it.

Instead:

`$('.btnUrl').click(function (e) {
  //Your ajax code
})`

Try using:

`$('#yourForm').submit(function (e) {
  //Your ajax code
  e.preventDefault();
})`